# Swift - Performance of `UIGestureRecognizer` when having many of them

Tags: ios, swift, performance, uigesturerecognizer

I've been thinking about this for quite some time now and I haven't found a suiting answer to this.

*How performant are `UIGestureRecognizer` in swift/iOS development?*

Let me explain by giving you a theoretical example:
You have an app on the iPad Pro (big screen, much space) and there you have maybe dozens of different `views` and `buttons` and so on. For whatever reason you need every one of these `views` and `buttons` to be moveable/clickable/resizable/...

What's better?

- **Adding one (or multiple) `UIGestureRecognizer(s)` to each view** (which results in many active gesture recognizers and many small, specific handling methods [maybe grouped for each type of `view`])
- **Adding one single recognizer to the `superview`** (which results in one active gesture recognizer and a big handling method that needs to cycle through the `subviews` and determine which one has been tapped)

I guess the first one is the most simple one but is it slower than the second one? I'm not sure about that. My stomach tells me that having that many `UIGestureRecognizers` can't be a good solution.

But either way, the system has to cycle through everything (in the worst case), be it many recognizers or many `subviews`. I'm curious about this.

Thank you

Comment: >>> For whatever reason you need every one of these views and buttons to be moveable/clickable/resizable/... 
You need it in one moment for all items or based on some state only part of them must be moveable/clickable/resizable/ ?

Comment: "(...) by giving you a theoretical example (...)" - It's not something concrete or real, I don't make an app with this or something. It's a theoretical worst case scenario in which you need to be able to move/click/resize every single view you see on the screen. Not for a single moment, but forever, basically. At any given moment, you should be able to move/tap/... any view you'd like.

Answer (score 1):

Let look at your question in terms of gesture recognition flow -> to pass event to the right gesture recognize the system goes by the views tree to find last one specific to this gesture, that will return true in one specific method of UIView
 `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

- Adding one (or multiple) UIGestureRecognizer(s) to each view

This way I recommended to use. In this case the system will do most of the work for you and prevent you from mistakes that very difficult to debug later - trust me. This is for UI. Especially if you have multiple different gestures on different parts of a screen. In my particular case I have a huge video player UI that has around 20 gesture recognizers on one screen and feels pretty good - no lags or frame drop in UI. this way is simple and self describing. I recommend implement it using storyboard or xib. You can refer to Interface Builderand later any time to recall in a moment what recognizer should you update to change the behaviour of UI. The speed of this approach guaranteed by a system.

- Adding one single recognizer to the superview

This way could be used with only one simple gesture for a multiple views (more > 20). this could happened if you implementing some game where user pick up and paste a bricks of different shapes for example. It is not suitable for common UI tasks. The speed depends on your implementation, and based on question itself I  am not recommend to do it. This approach is design specific not speed relevant.